# DNNClassifier predict sample

Tags: tensorflow

Based on the [Tensorflow tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/tutorials/tflearn/index.html), we see that it's easy to use the DNNClassifier to make a basic class prediction given sample data. But is there a way to get sample data given a class?

Specifically for the given example, can I give it the class 2 and get the four points of data it'd most associate with a flower of that class.

Answer (score 0):

The classifier exports keys other than accuracy. Using `"scores"` will give you the score for each example in each class, which you can then loop over to find the max.